# String out of range [Python]

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that combines two words together in python. 
For example, if I am combining "hello" and "chadd" it will return "hcehlaldod" by alternating letters.

Heres my code:

```
string1 = "hey"
string2 = "hii"
len1 = len(str(string1))
len2 = len(str(string2))
x = 0
final = ""

while (x <= len1):
  final = final + string1[x] + string2[x]
  x = x + 1
```

any help?

Comment: You are iterating out of bounds. Python string is starting indexing from `0` to `len(string)-1`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simplest way of to do that like this:

```
string1 = "hey"
string2 = "hii"
new_str = ""

for char1,char2 in zip(string1, string2):
    new_str += char1 + char2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(new_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `while (x <= len1)` to `while (x < len1)` if you only care about the length of the first string.

If you care about the length of both strings, do `while (x < len1 and x < len2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem with your loop is because you're using the condition `while (x <= len1):`

Let me explain. The length of your string is 3. The characters (and their indexes) are as follows:

```
0 1 2
h e y
```

You will see your string ends at index position 2. So now go back to your condition. You have set it to continue looping `while (x <= len1):`. So your loop will operate when `x=0`, `x=1`, `x=2` and `x=3`. The `x=3` is out of bounds since the indexes for your string end at index position 2.

What you should use is `while (x < len1):` which will stop at the correct point in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can pay attention to the lengths, as others have suggested, but you can also take a more functional approach with the built in `zip` function:

```
string1 = "hello"
string2 = "chadd"

string3 = ''.join(t[0] + t[1] for t in zip(string1, string2))  # hcehlaldod
```

`zip` works by pairing it's inputs:

```
print(list(zip(string1, string2)))  # note that you should turn it into a list to print it
# [('h', 'c'), ('e', 'h'), ('l', 'a'), ('l', 'd'), ('o', 'd')]
```

And you can then just combine those into a string (like my first code snippit does).